# C++: Elegant way to split string and stuff contents into std::vector

Tags: c++, string, split

I would like to split a string along whitespaces, and I know that the tokens
represent valid integers. I would like to transform the tokens into integers
and populate a vector with them.

I could use boost::split, make a vector of token strings, then use std::transform.

What is your solution? Using boost is acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) - see answer from @KeithB

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx They are very efficient and somewhat elegant. The String Toolkit Library makes complex string processing in C++ simple and easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
std::istringstream iss("42 4711 ");
std::vector<int> results( std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)
                        , std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tokenizer/introduc.htm).  It can easily be wrapped up into an `explode_string` function that takes a string and the delimiter and returns a vector of tokens.

Using `transform` on the returned vector is a good idea for the transformation from strings to ints; you can also just pass the Boost.Tokenizer iterator into the `transform` algorithm.

Comment: Is there a way of using boost::tokenizer with arbitrary tokens? It seems to work with characters like `' ', ',', '(', ')', ';'`. Is there a way to use for example `'m'` as a token?

Answer (score 1):

Use Boost's string algorithm library to `split` the string into a vector of strings, then `std::for_each` and either `atoi` or `boost::lexical_cast` to turn them into `int`s. It's likely to be far simpler than other methods, but may not have the greatest performance due to the copy (if someone has a way to improve it and remove that, please comment).

```
std::vector<int> numbers;

void append(std::string part)
{
    numbers.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<int>(part));
}

std::string line = "42 4711"; // borrowed from sbi's answer
std::vector<std::string> parts;
split(parts, line, is_any_of(" ,;"));
std::for_each(parts.being(), parts.end(), append);
```

Roughly.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/string_algo.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could always use strtok or string.find().